# Get index of density bin values of histogram in hist() R

Tags: r, histogram

I would like to get the index values of the bins in a histogram generated via `hist()`

Example and details follow:

```
testhist <- hist(rnorm(1000, 1000, 100), n = 5000, xlim = c(0,5000), probability = TRUE)
```

gives `testhist$density`, which are my 'y' values. So, in the code I define `n = 5000`, that is 5000 bins across `x 0:5000`. I would like to get the index value of the histogram bin each 'y' value corresponds to.

i.e:

```
Bin Index  |  'y' value
1           0
1           0.000005
1           0
1           0
1           0.0000001
2           0.00002
3           0
3           0.0002
...5000
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

EDIT: as commenters pointed out, `n=` is an approximation. So, lets do this:

```
testhist <- hist(rnorm(1000, 1000, 100), breaks = seq(0,5000, by = 5), xlim = c(0,5000), probability = TRUE)
```

Now, you would have 1000 exact bins. How to get the index of a bin corresponding to a 'y' value. i.e. bin 1, which has range of 0:5, has what `y` values in it?

EDIT 2: Each bin would correspond to a `density`, the more number of bins, the more representative the data would be. Thanks for steering me into the right direction.

Comment: `seq_along(testhist$density)` ? Each `density` value corresponds to the bins in ascending order in a 1:1 relationship as far as I know.

Comment: This won't give you an index. You will have multiple values in one bin - `seq_along` is indexing the values not the corresponding bin.

Comment: You will have multiple original values of your input to `hist` in a bin. You will only have 1 `density` per bin.

Comment: I really doubt that if you input `n=5000` means you will get a vector of length 5000. Not really. Try it out. The `density` is longer than 5000

Comment: @Onyambu - indeed. From `?hist`: *In the last three cases the number is a suggestion only; as the breakpoints will be set to pretty values*. (I think the argument is `breaks=` too, not `n=`, which only works by chance).

Comment: There are only 1000 sample numbers produced by rnorm.  Not 5000 through `breaks=5000`, or `xlim = c(0,5000)` which is only used in plotting.

Comment: thanks all for your comments; I edited the post, to have a fixed number of bins across a range. The questions still comesup on how can i get an index for each bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bit of confusion about what `hist` does or doesn't do here.

1. There is no `n=` argument to `hist`, only `breaks=`. I *think* It gives the same result by chance since `pretty()` uses `n=` and that function is used to define the bins.
2. Setting `breaks=5000` does not guarantee 5000 bins, as @Onyambu notes, due to `pretty()`-ification of the break-points. From `?hist`: *...the number is a suggestion only; as the breakpoints will be set to pretty values.*
3. `testhist$density` gives a density in *each* bin. You can verify this with:

---

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(1000, 1000, 100)
testhist <- hist(x, n=5000, xlim = c(0,5000), probability = TRUE)
length(testhist$mids)
#[1] 6820
length(testhist$density)
#[1] 6820
length(testhist$breaks)
#[1] 6821
```

6820 midpoints of bins, 6820 corresponding densities, and 6821 breaks since you need `n+1` breaks to give `n` bins.

The original 1000 data-points are represented in these 6820 bins, with many of the counts and corresponding densities being zero.

```
sum(testhist$counts)
#[1] 1000
sum(testhist$counts == 0)
#[1] 5954
sum(testhist$density == 0)
#[1] 5954
```

If you want to know which *original value of `x`* corresponds with which bin, you can do:

```
cut(x, testhist$breaks, labels=FALSE)
```

Comment: Check the edit on my post when you get a chance; but to your last point: I want the bin corresponding to the density values. Or maybe `hist()` is not the approach to do this?

Comment: @jackkelly - I admit I'm still lost with the edit. There's still one `density` per bin. 1000 densities, 1000 bins. If `density` is your `y` value, it is in one and only one bin.

Comment: yes, you are right. I completely mixed up different concepts. By defining bins, each bin would correspond to a `density` which is what i needed.